# I have Registered App ID but still it shows You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps. Register one here

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have Registered AppID.
Using Wild card and without Wold card also.

this is not first time i am creating app ID and submitting it on appstore.
But after registering appID on developer.apple.com

and when i try to add new app on itunesconnect.apple.com

it all time shows "You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps. Register one here."

I have created 4 appId for This.but till msg not disappears.

Answer (score 11):

Logging out and back in of iTunes Connect fixed this for me.

Answer (score 8):

seems a problem with iTunes Connect Contracts and payments. Here is a quote

> Had the same problem. Just had to update my contract & tax info and accept the new iAd contract and everything worked again (Even though I don't want to use iAd at all).

Seems to be working for them. Not sure though.I am gonna check it out.

Comment: Any tip on where I can update my contract & tax info?

Comment: Found it => iTunesConnect > Agreements, Tax, and Banking

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is something wrong with iTunes Connect now. I can't add new app either. Itunes connect doesn't see any of my recently added APP_STORE provisioning profiles.

Comment: it worked after few hours. It seems it take some time to have it updated.